# How to change UIBarButtunItem functionality programatically in Xcode swift

Tags: swift, xcode, function

In my Xcode project I have a Bar Button Item, and two @IBAction functions in swift file.
First is `@IBAction func editObjectsAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)`
and the second is `@IBAction func cancelAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)`.
When user clicks the button first time, first function starts to work. I want to make to start work the second function when user clicks the button next time. How can I organize that programmatically in first function?

Comment: Is it really required to use `IBAction` instead of in-code action listeners?

Comment: Is it possible to connect storyboard actions back to code without @IBAction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach looks uncommon to me. You better have one action, which can make subsequent call to corresponding methods depending on current state (which is not tied to the bar button). However, since the question itself is asking how to set a `UIBarButtonItem` action programmatically, I answer it below.

`UIBarButtonItem` has `target` and `action` properties, which have exposed setters. You can set them at runtime whenever you need, but your selectors must be available in obj-c runtime:

```
@objc private func editObjectAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    sender.action = #selector(cancelAction(_:))
}

@objc private func cancelAction (_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    sender.action = #selector(editObjectAction(_:))
}
```

Be advised that code above works only if the item target property is set to the methods' owner (most commonly it should be `self`)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of using two different @IBActions. You can make it work by doing the following steps:

**Step 1:**

Create one global boolean variable

```
var isFirstClickDone: Bool! = false
```

**Step 2**

Now create two different functions to accomplish functionalities you desire

```
func editAction() {
   // put the logic for edit in this method
}

func cancelAction() {
   // put the logic for cancel in this method
}
```

**Step 3**

Create an IBAction as you have already created, then assign it to your BarButton and place logic in that as given below

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    if !isFirstClickDone {

       editAction()
       isFirstClickDone = true

    }else {

       cancelAction()
       isFirstClickDone = false

    }

}
```